# Destroy object if NOT in collision?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Would like to know if it is possible to destroy an object if not in collision with anything?

When I start the game I generate a grid randomly, on each GridSquare I've made a collider2D. In the editor, I add some objects on this grid manually, with a collider2D too and a rigidbody2D to detect the collision.

I know how to destroy the object if in a collision, what I want is "when the game start, if this object is not in collision with anything, then destroy it"

I've tried to tell unity "if in collision with grid square then destroy object (just for testing), else destroy object"

```
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.name == "GridSquare")
    {
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    else {
    Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

So actually it destroys well the object when it is on a GridSquare, and it should destroy object if it is not in collision with GridSquare too but apparently not...

Answer (score 2):

```
private var collisionCount = 0;

void OnCollisionEnter () {
    collisionCount++
}

void OnCollisionExit () {
    collisionCount--;
}

void checkForCollision(){
if(0 == collisionCount) Destroy(gameObject);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the gameObject is not colliding, OnTriggerEnter2D method wont be activated for that specific gameObject. Bear in mind that method only triggers on collision event.
For that case you might have in your gameObjects a boolean _isColliding which you can change with the OnTriggerEnter2D method to check the ones that are colliding, setting that to true.

```
bool _isColliding = false;
void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    _isColliding = true;
}
```

Then you loop through all of the gameObjects and destroy only the ones that have the _isColliding == false.

Hope that helps!